# Using attribute values as choices in Django model

Tags: django

I want the user to be able to add values to an attribute `'county'` in model `CountyChoices`. I then want those values to surface as choices in a form for address for the attribute `'county'` in model `Address`.

I couldn't think of another way to explain this and so I had a hard time finding this in the documentation. What would this be called in the Django docs so that I can look this up?

Comment: You could have a `ForeignKey` field in `Address` model pointing to `CountyChoices`. Check Django many-to-one docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using Django ForeignKey

```
class Address(models.Model):
    conutry = models.ForeignKey('Country')

class Country(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
```